# I can't connect to ethernet but can connet to wifi

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, ethernet

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. Here is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
-> ~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:e2:27:ea  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:89000 (89.0 KB)  TX bytes:89000 (89.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:f0:2f:3b:22:d2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b147:93a0:c0e5:7ae6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4132 (4.1 KB)  TX bytes:7730 (7.7 KB)
```

On windows I can connect the ethernet, I have restarted the network-manager, won't work.

```
-> ~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

After add add `iface eth0 inet dhcp` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and executing `ifdown -a`,  command `ifup -a` gives:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/3c:97:0e:e2:27:ea
Sending on   LPF/eth0/3c:97:0e:e2:27:ea
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb3b79015)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0xb3b79015)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Here is my driver infomation:

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at dbc04000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at dbc00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

-> ~$ dmesg | grep r8169
[    1.129765] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    1.130652] r8169 0000:09:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.143154] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc9000067a000, 3c:97:0e:e2:27:ea, XID 0c900800 IRQ 27
[    1.144101] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   25.526338] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
```

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @JosephR. posted

Comment: What happens if you add `iface eth0 inet dhcp` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and run `ifup eth0`?

Comment: ^ When you run that test, make sure you disconnect your wireless connection.

Comment: @JosephR. When I do `ifdown -a` and `ifup -a`, the following comes and seems not stopping... I'm posting it to the post

Comment: @JosephR. I have updated the post, seems not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution on AskUbuntu for [Realtek ethernet driver error ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770368/realtek-ethernet-driver-error-ubuntu-16-04) suggests you need an updated driver

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Comment: This works great, my ethernet Led start to blink again!